# Why my useEffect that tries to get blockchain data is looping infinitely and my async func still returns Promise pending

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

I am trying to use async await inside a useEffect hook getting some data from a testnet blockchain but I am getting 2 problems:

1. The async function returns a Promise, why is that? Shouldn't async await automatically resolve the promise and give me the data? I tried to solve it with Promise.resolve but not working, it still tells me campaigns is a Promise in pending state.
2. It enters in an infinite loop and I still do not get why.

Here is the code:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const getCampaigns = async() => {
      const campaigns = await factory.methods.getDeployedCampaigns().call()
      return campaigns
    }
    const campaigns = getCampaigns();
    setCampaigns(Promise.resolve(campaigns));

    console.log('campaigns: ', campaigns);
  })
```

Comment: 1. Because it's an async function.

Comment: I see async functions return Promises but should Promise.resolve work?

Comment: `Promise.resolve` creates a promise that resolves to the value you pass it. It doesn't resolve the promise (which you can't do synchronously _because it's a promise_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no dependencies array.

```
useEffect(() => {
   const getCampaigns = async() => {
      const campaigns = await factory.methods.getDeployedCampaigns().call()
      return campaigns
   }
   
   const campaigns = getCampaigns();
   setCampaigns(Promise.resolve(campaigns));
   console.log('campaigns: ', campaigns);
}, [])
```

Comment: Yes, that solves the infinite loop, thx. Forgot about the dependency array. But the call is till returning a Promise that it is not solved with Promise.resolve.

Comment: move setCampaigns... and set it just after const campaigns = await... setCampaigns(campaigns)

You are resolving a promise with the await, and returning the value. However, in setCampaigns you are creating a new Promise

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
useEffect(() => {
  const getCampaigns = async() => {
    const campaigns = await factory.methods.getDeployedCampaigns().call()
    setCampaigns(campaigns);
  }

  getCampaigns();
}, []);
```

The empty array in useEffect call makes it behave like component did mount and only executes once (assuming factory methods are initialized on mount) and since the getDeployedCompanigns Promise is already resolved I'm simply setting the state in the getCampaigns function.

Read this article for details: https://devtrium.com/posts/async-functions-useeffect